# How to initialize a EC key pair with an existing key pair in JavaCard?

Tags: java, key, javacard

I already have a EC key pair(secp256r1) in a binary format which is stored in a byte array, like this:

```
// private key, 32 bytes
byte[] privKey = {0x4c, (byte)0xc7, (byte)0xcf, 0x68, (byte)0x91, 0x18, (byte)0x96, (byte)0xc8, (byte)0xe2, (byte)0xf9, (byte)0xc8, (byte)0xcc, 0x2f, 0x7f, 0x0a, (byte)0xa2, 0x1c, 0x6a, (byte)0xcb, (byte)0xba, 0x38, 0x1c, 0x10, (byte)0x9a, (byte)0xfe, (byte)0x91, 0x18, (byte)0xf6, (byte)0xca, (byte)0xd9, 0x0f, 0x0b};
//public key, 65 bytes, which is contained in a X.509 certificate
byte[] pubKey = {0x04, 0x72, (byte)0x9a, 0x71, (byte)0xd0, (byte)0x81, 0x62, 0x42, (byte)0x84, (byte)0x92, (byte)0xf2, (byte)0xd9, 0x61, (byte)0x92, 0x4d, 0x37, 0x44, 0x3a, 0x4f, 0x1b, (byte)0xda, 0x58, 0x0f, (byte)0x8a, (byte)0xea, 0x29, 0x20, (byte)0xd2, (byte)0x99, 0x7c, (byte)0xbe, (byte)0xa4, 0x39, 0x60, (byte)0xce, 0x72, (byte)0x9e, 0x35, (byte)0xc1, (byte)0xf7, 0x40, (byte)0x92, (byte)0xf2, 0x25, 0x0e, 0x60, 0x74, (byte)0x82, 0x3f, (byte)0xc5, 0x7f, 0x33, 0x60, (byte)0xb7, (byte)0xcd, 0x39, 0x69, (byte)0xc3, (byte)0xc3, 0x12, 0x5e, (byte)0xce, 0x26, 0x5c, 0x29};
```

This EC key pair is generated by openssl. I want to store this EC key pair in my javacard applet, so that I can signature message with this EC private key every time.

But I don't find any appropriate API in javacard 3 to set the EC key pair.

I use this project https://github.com/Yubico/ykneo-curves/blob/master/applet/src/com/yubico/ykneo/curves/SecP256r1.java to set the parameters in secp256r1.

**UPDATE**
I do have set the parameters setW in ECPublicKey and setS in ECPrivateKey, and other parameters according to https://github.com/Yubico/ykneo-curves/blob/master/applet/src/com/yubico/ykneo/curves/SecP256r1.java. Like this:

```
    privKey.setFieldFP(p, (short) 0, (short) p.length);
    privKey.setA(a, (short) 0, (short) a.length);
    privKey.setB(b, (short) 0, (short) b.length);
    privKey.setG(G, (short) 0, (short) G.length);
    privKey.setR(r, (short) 0, (short) r.length);

    byte[] privData = {(byte)0x25, (byte)0xc9, (byte)0xec, (byte)0xdc, (byte)0x4c, (byte)0x59, (byte)0xa3, (byte)0xe0, (byte)0x4f, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x56, (byte)0x97, (byte)0xf3, (byte)0xcb, (byte)0x60, (byte)0x5b, (byte)0x84, (byte)0x49, (byte)0x45, (byte)0x3a, (byte)0xe2, (byte)0x0e, (byte)0xd1, (byte)0xbd, (byte)0xc0, (byte)0xa7, (byte)0xe1, (byte)0xfa, (byte)0x82, (byte)0xee, (byte)0x3c, (byte)0x73};
    privKey.setS(privData, (short) 0, (short) privData.length);

    pubKey.setFieldFP(p, (short) 0, (short) p.length);
    pubKey.setA(a, (short) 0, (short) a.length);
    pubKey.setB(b, (short) 0, (short) b.length);
    pubKey.setG(G, (short) 0, (short) G.length);
    pubKey.setR(r, (short) 0, (short) r.length);

    byte[] pubData = {0x04, 0x00, (byte)0xb9, (byte)0x8f, (byte)0xcf, (byte)0xc3, (byte)0xc0, (byte)0xae, (byte)0x95, 0x6a, 0x5b, 0x12, 0x6d, (byte)0xbe, 0x43, (byte)0xe4, 0x7f, 0x09, 0x0d, (byte)0xde, 0x02, (byte)0xd2, 0x6b, 0x28, (byte)0x86, (byte)0xed, 0x2b, (byte)0xd7, (byte)0xe2, (byte)0xc2, 0x69, (byte)0xc1, (byte)0x89, (byte)0xb2, 0x53, (byte)0x96, (byte)0xc1, 0x2d, (byte)0xbf, 0x4c, 0x30, (byte)0xae, (byte)0xd5, (byte)0xd5, 0x3c, (byte)0xb5, (byte)0xf9, 0x3b, 0x20, 0x37, (byte)0x83, (byte)0x88, (byte)0x9f, 0x34, 0x74, (byte)0xf5, 0x6c, (byte)0x97, 0x1e, 0x0a, (byte)0xa9, (byte)0xe7, (byte)0xfa, (byte)0xa6, 0x69};
    pubKey.setW(pubData, (short) 0, (short)pubData.length);
```

Now I signature the message:

```
    // the class Secp256r1 can be found in above link
    pair = SecP256r1.newKeyPair();

    ECPublicKey pubKey = (ECPublicKey) pair.getPublic();
    ECPrivateKey privKey = (ECPrivateKey) pair.getPrivate();


    byte[] data = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f};


    signature = Signature.getInstance(Signature.ALG_ECDSA_SHA, false);
    signature.init(pair.getPrivate(), Signature.MODE_SIGN);

    byte[] signData = new byte[127];
    short sendLen = signature.sign(data, (short) 0, (short) data.length, buffer, (short) 0);
    apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, sendLen);
```

I send several APDUs to call this code fragment. But every time I receive a differnt sign message. Why should this happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are methods `setW(...)` on `ECPublicKey` and `setS(...)` on `ECPrivateKey`.

The tricky part is that your `keyPair.getPublic()` and `keyPair.getPrivate()` return general interfaces. You have to cast them:

```
KeyPair keyPair = new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_EC_FP, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_EC_FP_256);
ECPublicKey pub = (ECPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
ECPrivateKey priv = (ECPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
pub.setW(pubBytes, (short) 0, (short) pubBytes.length);
priv.setS(privBytes, (short) 0, (short) privBytes.length);
//do not forget to set parameters of your curve to both private and public key HERE!!!
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/security/ECPublicKey.html

> void setW(byte[] buffer,
>           short offset,
>           short length)
>             throws CryptoException
>
> Sets the point of the curve comprising the public key. The point
>   should be specified as an octet string as per ANSI X9.62. A specific
>   implementation need not support the compressed form, but must support
>   the uncompressed form of the point. The plain text data format is
>   big-endian and right-aligned (the least significant bit is the least
>   significant bit of last byte). Input parameter data is copied into the
>   internal representation.

https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/security/ECPrivateKey.html

> void setS(byte[] buffer,
>           short offset,
>           short length)
>             throws CryptoException
>
> Sets the value of the secret key. The plain text data format is
>   big-endian and right-aligned (the least significant bit is the least
>   significant bit of last byte). Input parameter data is copied into the
>   internal representation.

**ANSWER to UPDATE:**

Signatures based on an elliptic curve contain a random number, that is why you get a different result each time you compute a signature. It is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: I update my question after following your advise. But I get a new problem: the signature message is different every time. This should be caused by different EC key pairs used by signature every time?

Comment: I will send the signature and the EC public key to the off-card side(like Android phone' app). As the off-card side do not know the random number, can it verify this signature using the public key? Thank you for your help @vojta

Comment: @YangZhou Yes, of course. The random number is written inside your output signature bytes. Off-card side will need only the public key and the signature, no other extra information.